# Using a function inside NavigationView throws error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyView.Type' to return type 'AnyView'

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I have a problem with calling my function. Its not the first function i wrote in this app but this is .. "different" xD

Currently I try to show some items with description, amount and the type. And right next to the type a little icon should be shown.

I would like to save the type of icon with a String so it should looks like this:

User choose type of ingredients, e.g. "Getränke" and this value is saved in my type variable.My function myImage is called and save this type of ingredients in my itemImage value and my itemImage value is connected with a picture. Like in my Switch case below - the user choose "Getränke" the variable type = Getränke and my switch case picked this value and saved it also in itemImage. (for my test case there is only one picture, calles "Drogerie" thats why every case is the same ;o

Basically this is my current code for my view:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Picker("Rezept oder Zutat", selection: $rezeptOrIngredients){
                ForEach(Self.subTitle, id: \.self)
                {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }

            if rezeptOrIngredients == "Zutat" {
                Picker("Type", selection: $type){
                    ForEach(Self.types, id:\.self){
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                TextField("Beschreibung", text: $beschreibung)
                HStack{
                    TextField("Menge", text: $menge)
                    Picker(selection: $unitType, label: Text("Anzahl Personen")){
                        ForEach(Self.units, id:\.self)
                        {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                //My function////
                myImage()
                }
               } 
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Hinzufügen von...")
    }
```

And of course my code for the function:

```
func myImage() -> AnyView{
    switch type {
    case "Nahrungsmittel": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Haushaltsartikel": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Getränke": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Obst und Gemüse": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Tiefkühl": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Drogerie und Kosmetik": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Baby und Kind": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Tierartikel": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Süßigkeiten und Salzigkeiten": itemImage = "Drogerie"

    default: itemImage = "empty"
    }
    return AnyView //Shows Error
}
```

I already understood why I need a function which is return a view but to be honest I cant understand what this AnyView type means respectively what my function needs to return...

Thank you for your help! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you meant the following (however it is not clear what is `type` and what is `itemImage`, `cause not visible declarations):

```
func myImage() -> some View {
    switch type {
    case "Nahrungsmittel": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Haushaltsartikel": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Getränke": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Obst und Gemüse": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Tiefkühl": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Drogerie und Kosmetik": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Baby und Kind": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Tierartikel": itemImage = "Drogerie"
    case "Süßigkeiten und Salzigkeiten": itemImage = "Drogerie"

    default: itemImage = "empty"
    }
    return Image(itemImage)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a long while to find this, but to return an AnyView, you simply do:

```
func someFunc() -> AnyView {
    return AnyView(EmptyView()) // Or AnyView(Text(...)) etc.
}
```